# Adding header files to g++ command

Tags: c++, g++

Im trying to manually add my header file path to g++

```
Adams-MBP:randomCode naghs$ g++ -o
-I/Users/naghs/randomCode/lib/StanfordCPPLib/collections/lexicon.h test test.cpp
test.cpp:5:10: fatal error: 'lexicon.h' file not found
#include "lexicon.h"
     ^~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

What is the correct way to do that because I would've thought that "-I" does that

Comment: `-I` does not add a file. It adds a directory where files can be found. Try `-I/Users/naghs/randomCode/lib/StanfordCPPLib/collections/`.

Comment: Once you start to spend time creating/passing large arguments to g++ it's highly recommend to start using Cmake.

Answer (score 0):

It's `-I/Users/naghs/randomCode/lib/StanfordCPPLib/collections`. It specifies a directory, not a file.

Answer (score -1):

The `-I` flag takes a directory, not an individual header file.

For more info, see [gcc/g++ Directory Options docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html#Directory-Options).

I also believe you have an incorrect argument after the `-o` flag. I think you want

```
g++ -I/Users/naghs/randomCode/lib/StanfordCPPLib/collections -o test test.cpp
```

You should have the output path immediately after the `-o` flag.